# Calling an Array from an Object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

in my class SummerStats I need to create another method that locates the largest element of the array created in my method setSalaries. How can I call the array, "salaries" to another method in the same class?

```
class SummerStats
 {
   public SummerStats()
   {

   }
   public int[][] setSalaries(int people, int years)
   { 
      int[][] salaries = new int[people][years];

   //rows respresent people and columns represent years
      for (people = 0; people < salaries.length; people++)
      {
         for (years = 0; years < salaries[people].length; years++)
         {
            salaries[people][years] = (int)(1000 + Math.random()*1000);
         }
      }

      return salaries;
   }
```

Also, my test class is

```
import java.util.*;
public class testSummerStats
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   SummerStats one = new SummerStats();
   System.out.println("Enter people, then years: ");
   int x = input.nextInt();
   int y = input.nextInt();
   one.setSalaries(x, y);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Look at using [instance variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in your `SummerStats` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your 2D-Array as a member variable. This way it will be accessible to all the methods of the class:

```
class SummerStats
 {
   private int[][] salaries;

   public SummerStats()
   {

   }

   public void setSalaries(int people, int years)
   { 
      salaries = new int[people][years]; // initialize the array

   //rows respresent people and columns represent years
      for (people = 0; people < salaries.length; people++)
      {
         for (years = 0; years < salaries[people].length; years++)
         {
            salaries[people][years] = (int)(1000 + Math.random()*1000);
         }
      }

   }
    public void locateMax() {
        // Your code goes here. (You can access the salaries array)
    }
}
```

Then create a new method (`locateMax` i.e) that will calculate the max number of the 2D-array.

Answer (score 1):

`setSalaries` should not return the array. Assign the array to a field of `SummerStats` instead. Then add another method to `SummerStats` for locating the largest element.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign your array to a field. and access it outside. or second option you can pass pass this array to new method and there you can do operations for finding out largest element.

Answer (score 0):

**Your current program:**

```
class SummerStats
 {
   public SummerStats()
   {

   }
   public int[][] setSalaries(int people, int years)
   **{** 
      int[][] salaries = new int[people][years];
      ....
      return salaries;
   **}**
}
```

**Solution:**

```
class SummerStats
 **{**
   private int[][] salaries;

   public SummerStats()
   {

   }
   public int[][] setSalaries(int people, int years)
   { 
      salaries = new int[people][years];
      ....
      return salaries;
   }
**}**
```

In your current program is the variable `salaries` declared as a local variable of the method `setSalaries` and therefore its scope is limited to the scope of the method. In the solution program is the variable `salaries` declared as a member variable/field of the class `SummerStats` and therefore its scope is limited to the scope of all member method/variable declarations of the class.